# Hide copy option from UiMenucontroller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I want to remove copy and define option from `UIMenuViewcontroller`

i checked on Google and got the i have to override below method in my class and done same

Add below in subclass of `UIWebView`

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender{
 NSLog(@"action=========%@",NSStringFromSelector(action));
     if(action == @selector(copy:)
        return NO;

    }
```

But i am not getting ant option named copy: but getting all other like cut:, paste:, select: etc, but copy: option is not coming, so i cant hide the copy option until i get copy option in above method

Please tell me what i have to do , why copy option is not coming

i am getting below actions there is no copy action

```
2014-02-13  action=========cut:

2014-02-13  action=========select:

2014-02-13  action=========selectAll:

2014-02-13  action=========paste:

2014-02-13  action=========delete:

2014-02-13  action=========_promptForReplace:

2014-02-13  action=========_showTextStyleOptions:

2014-02-13  action=========_addShortcut:

2014-02-13  action=========_accessibilitySpeak:

2014-02-13  action=========_accessibilitySpeakLanguageSelection:

2014-02-13  action=========_accessibilityPauseSpeaking:

2014-02-13  action=========makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft:

2014-02-13  action=========makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight:
```

Comment: What do you mean "not coming"? Your code looks OK (`copy:` is the correct method, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/UIResponderStandardEditActions.html)) except selector needs a lower case s and you have to return YES for the other actions.

Comment: Put break point and check whether this delegate method get called?

Comment: @jrturton When i print action then getting all cut,paste, select but copy action is not there

Comment: @jrturton  i am able to hide all other but copy action is not there

Comment: Your log statement is after the return statement, so it will never get executed when the action is copy. Move it to above the line where you check the action.

Comment: See updates, similar result in that case too

Answer (score -1):

Add call `[super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender]` to your implementation

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {  
    if (action == @selector(copy:))
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Comment: I think you need also override `canPerformAction` in `UIViewController` that contain `UIWebView`